# How to access my object inside onClick(View v) function?

Tags: android

I have defined a model class:

```
public class MyObject {
    ...
}
```

In my activity, I get this object from SERVICE layer. Everything works fine at this point, my only question is, in Activity, if I set ***setOnClickListener*** to a ***TextView***, how can I access **myObject**? What I mean is showing in the following code:

```
//my custom object
MyObject obj = SERVICE.getObject();

TextView tx = new TextView(this);
tx.setText("Click me");
tx.setOnClickListener(
     new OnClickListener(){

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){

                //how to access obj here? 
             }
      }
);
```

In the above code, I **can not** access `obj` inside `onClick(View v)` function, how to get rid of it to access `obj` inside `onClick(View v)` ?

Comment: Either you have to declare myObj as final or as Global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ID, you can set that ID on the tag field and retrieve it in the onclick:

```
tx.setTag(obj.getId());
tx.setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Long id = v.getTag();
        }
    }
);
```

You can store an arbitrary object, so you could potentially store the whole object there.

Answer (score 3):

Mark `MyObject obj` as `final`.

```
final MyObject obj = SERVICE.getObject();

TextView tx = new TextView(this);
tx.setText("Click me");
tx.setOnClickListener(
     new OnClickListener(){

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                obj.doStuff(); //this should work now...
             }
      }
);
```

Comment: @towpse Thanks, link removed.

Answer (score 0):

Set your object as **final** and you can get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler method:

```
class testClass
{
    testClass obj;
    public testClass() {
        obj=this;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView tx = new TextView(this);
        tx.setText("Click me");
        tx.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    obj.doStuff(); //this should work now...
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```